# AMD Ryzen 7 3700X - Which RAM?

Tags: cpu, amd-ryzen

it's time for a new computer. 32GB and RGB would be perfect. Now I have to decide which RAM I buy, but I have some questions:

1.) 2x 16GB or 4x 8GB? What's better?

2.) The max. Memory clock frequency is 3200MHz. Can I use 3600MHz RAM or will they stop at 3200MHz?

3.) What is the best RAM for a AMD Ryzen 7 3700X?

4.) What else should I consider?

Mainboard: It will be an ATX X570 from ASUS or MSI, but I'm still not sure which I should buy.

Comment: Questions seeking for hardware shopping recommendations are off-topic because they are often relevant only to the question author at the time the question was asked and tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead of asking what to buy, try asking how to find out what suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that Ryzen processors generally favor faster RAM. 
Having said this you should look at the manufacturers website and look at their qualified vendor list (QVL).
Asus for instance has a CPU/Memory support list up on their site. 
Go there and look at what works for your processor and motherboard combo, find the price point you're comfortable with and purchase.

Matisse cores, which are Zen 2 architecture support dual channel Ram up to DDR4 3200, but that may differ between board Manufacturers.

Picasso cores, wich are Zen+ architecture support dual channel Ram up to DDR4 2400 speeds. Again check manufacturer site for specific vendors, some might be able to push higher clock speeds with over clocking.